# DB2 Copy data from staging table to main table with no table locking

Tags: copy, db2

I have 2 tables (1 staging table and 1 main operational table). 
Both tables have the same structure.

For my solution,

1. I am using DB2Copy in program to insert 10000 records into staging table (4 seconds)
2. From the staging table, will move the data into main table using stored procedure (10 seconds)
3. However, it will lock the main table when running stored procedure.
4. I am suspecting because of the BEGIN and END which cause the stored procedure to act like a transaction.
5. I do not want the table to be locked when running stored procedure. (any suggestion?) 
     Prefer: Stored procedure insert record by record into main table without transaction behavior.

Below is my code:

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE SP_NAME ( ) 
  LANGUAGE SQL
  NOT DETERMINISTIC
  CALLED ON NULL INPUT
  EXTERNAL ACTION
  OLD SAVEPOINT LEVEL
  MODIFIES SQL DATA
  INHERIT SPECIAL REGISTERS
  BEGIN 
    --DECLARE TEMP VARIABLES

    BEGIN
        DECLARE MYCURSOR CURSOR WITH RETURN TO CALLER FOR
        --SELECT STAGING TABLE
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET AT_END = 1;

        OPEN MYCURSOR;
            -- FETCH MYCURSOR INTO TEMP VARIABLES

        WHILE AT_END = 0 DO

            -- INSERT MAIN TABLE
            -- FETCH MYCURSOR INTO TEMP VARIABLES

        END WHILE;
        CLOSE MYCURSOR;
    END;
END;
```

My Environment

1. I have a program "A" which is trying to insert 10k records into main table (A lot of indexes and high volume of data) which takes 10 minutes ++.

About main operational table

1. High number of read but minimum updates and inserts at front end.
2. At back end, another program will frequently insert record into this table.
3. Only 1 instance of the back end program is allowed to run at one time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the procedure, make sure your commitment-control setting is  *NONE (a.k.a. autocommit). This should not lock your whole table

Adding the example

```
CREATE PROCEDURE userS.SP_TEST (                            
IN col_DATA Varchar(10) )                                   
LANGUAGE SQL                                                
SPECIFIC userS.SP_TEST                                      
NOT DETERMINISTIC                                           
MODIFIES SQL DATA                                           
SET OPTION COMMIT = *NONE                                   
BEGIN INSERT INTO userS.TABLE1 VALUES(col_DATA);            
END
```

Comment: Dear Userusher, how should i set this?

Comment: Thx for you answer. Referring to ibm website https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.cli.doc/doc/r0010308.html, this is definitely what i want. However, i dont know how to implement this. I added into my stored procedure code, but when executing CREATE STORED PROCEDURE code, it give me an error SQL0104N.

Comment: Its should be done with SET OPTION  COMMIT=*NONE in the procedure, do you mind posting what you tried?

Comment: Dear uSeruSher, using the code at my question, i have tried adding the piece of code "SET OPTION COMMIT=*NONE" in any part of my CREATE STORED PROCEDURE code but still fail to CREATE STORED PROCEDURE. Appreciate if you could give me an example to do so.

Comment: CREATE PROCEDURE userS.SP_TEST (                            
IN col_DATA Varchar(10) )                                   
LANGUAGE SQL                                                
SPECIFIC userS.SP_TEST                                      
NOT DETERMINISTIC                                           
MODIFIES SQL DATA                                           
SET OPTION COMMIT = *NONE                                   
BEGIN INSERT INTO userS.TABLE1 VALUES(col_DATA);            
END

Comment: Dear uSeruSher, thx for your reply and effort but i still cannot make it work... It prompt SQL0104N

Comment: I am pretty sure there is some syntax error involved. If you post the update code, we might check. WE can move to chat section if you prefer.

Comment: Dear uSeruSher, thx for your help. I think i have some concept misunderstanding here. After further research, below is my conclusion: 1. Every Insert will definitely lock the table. (how long it locks depend how fast the query is) 2. I managed to solve this problem by using INSERT INTO...SELECT for every 1000 records. 3. With this method, it does not lock the table for and long can provide good performance as well.